# Looking for dummy data aka passport images or other IDs

Tags: images, passports

We're training a machine learning tool to recognize passport and drivers license information as part of screening them for public benefits, we're trying to find samples of false/dummy passport and other IDs to train the mode on. Do these exist anywhere as open government/corporate data?

Comment: why did you make that tag? why did you make it and not define it?

Comment: forgot the space between them, typo.

Comment: 419 scammers will sometimes send these, and 419 scambaiters will as well. My own http://oneoff.barrycarter.info/419/IMAGES/ has a few I've collected from scammers, but some of these aren't passport pictures and others may be real-but-stolen passport scans. You might also google 'make fake passport online" (no quotes) and generate some from there.